# Website with no page refresh using nodeJs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to build a website using node.js. I want the content to be loaded without page refresh. I'm familiar with the AJAX way of doing so. But, does someone has any idea, how to achieve the same using NodeJs?

Here's what I'm currently doing (I don't think it's the only way):

> Place a middleware in between all the GET request (As on any refresh
>   action, there will be a GET request). Here, send all the basic
>   components of the site (I call it the main-stage). All the basic
>   layout, stylesheets gets loaded.
>
> When the request completely finishes, client fires an XHR request,
>   based on the current address. The request returns the html that needs
>   to be shown as the content.
>
> When XHR completes, setting the retrieved HTML to my "main-content"
>   iFrame.

Can someone tell me, is there any other way to do the same?

**Thank You.**

Comment: same even with nodejs (: just use expressjs add some route and do ajax response from clientside.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a lot of luck is Gulp, using the plugin gulp-connect. I am building an API with Node.js and Express.Js but still resort to Gulp for all my automation not matter the type of project.

http://gulpjs.com/

Using Gulp opens many doors to enhance your workflow automation such as minifying code, compressing images, copy/pasting files etc.

Hope you have as much luck with it as I do.

Here is how it wuld look for your server.

```
// Add requiements
var gulp        = require ('gulp'),
    connect     = require ('gulp-connect');


var jsSources;


//Setup path variables

jsSources   =   [ 
                    'builds/development/components/scripts/*.js'
                ];


//Javascript Files
gulp.task('js', function(){
    gulp.src(jsSources)
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

// Watch all sources file directorys and run tasks if changes happen.
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(jsSources,   ['js']);

});


// Start a server for project.
gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
    root : '',
    livereload : true,
    fallback: 'builds/development/index.html'
    });
});


// Run all tasks above by using default command "Gulp".
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'connect']);
```

Once this is setup you would just CD in your termincal and type Gulp

Answer (score 0):

This types of websites are called single paged website...you can load a page without refreshing the page.

You can achieve this by using ajax and history.pushState( ) function.

First you load the page by sending get request to the server using ajax.

When the server sends a .html page on response , load this page on a div element.

At same time you also change the browser history using history.pushState() function.

So that the page appears to be changed without refreshing.